# Delete file from directory in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I wrote some code in MVC a year ago and my knowledge of the framework seems to have vanished. In the code block below, I list all the files in a directory and provide a link to download them (for authenticated users). What I want to do is give the option to delete each file as well. I just added a delete button, but I am not sure where to go from there?

```
@{IEnumerable<string> enumerateFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Documents"));}
@{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <h3>Authenticated User: @User.Identity.Name</h3>
        <h4>-Downloadable Files-</h4>
<ul>

    @foreach (var fullPath in enumerateFiles)
    {         
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);

             <li> <a href="../../Content/Documents/@fileName"> @fileName</a>
             <button type="button"  id="fileRemover" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" >Delete</button> 
             </li>
    }
</ul>
    }
else
{
     <h3>Non-Authenticate User, register and/or login to see documents</h3>
}
}
```

Comment: You should move all of your C# out of your View. This will re-jig your memory about the difference between server-side and client-side.

Answer (score 0):

The code for viewing files and deleting files should be contained within the controller.  Your view is meant for simply displaying information (usually from your model) back to the user.

If I were you, I would structure my controller like this:

```
public class FilesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        List<FileInfo> model = new List<FileInfo>();
        //  Grab all file names from the directory and place them within the model.

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult View(string fileName)
    {
        //  Add header for content type
        //  Grab (and verify) file based on input parameter fileName

        return File(...);
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(string fileName)
    {
        //  Verify file exists
        //  Delete file if it exists

        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried to do. I could not figure out how to pass the filename to the Delete action. I had within the view                 @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                }

Comment: Based on your example above, there are really two ways it could be done:  a) Have delete links with the file name as part of the querystring (this assumes your Delete action can use GET HTTP verb).  Something like:  <a href="/Files/Delete?fileName=abc.txt">Delete</a>  b) Have a bit of javascript that fires when the delete button is clicked.  The javascript will populate a hidden form field (id="fileName").  Once the hidden field is populated, submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

The filename should come as a HTTP POST variable.

So you must create an hidden field  to hold the file name so that you can access the value on the action when the form is submitted.

Above the action name you would use the [HttpPost] attribute so that form submit lands on this action.

It is safe to have a HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET otherwise anyone with a url will be able to delete a file.

If you have multiple file names, then each hidden field can have the name as filename_1, filename_2 etc.

I have given you the direction where to look & investigate.